# brackets cannot be displayed correctly in hexo blog

Tags: javascript, blogs, hexo

I tried to build a personal blog using Github page and hexo. I am using matery theme. However, brackets in the code area cannot be displayed correctly in hexo blog. Instead, it is shown {. I am not sure what changes I made.
The code now looks like this.

```java
public class Client &#123;
    public static void main() &#123;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeInt(1);
```

I am unfamiliar with front end matter, and I do not know what I have changed. I used to suspect there is something wrong with my /node_modules/marked/lib/marked.js. However, I went to https://github.com/markedjs/marked/tree/master/lib to download a new one. It still does not work. Can someone please help me?

The inline part in marked.js

```js
  var inline = {
    escape: /^\\([!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\]\\^_`{|}~])/,
    // escape: /^\\([`*\[\]()#$+\-.!_>])/,
    autolink: /^<(scheme:[^\s\x00-\x1f<>]*|email)>/,
    url: noopTest$1,
    tag: '^comment' + '|^</[a-zA-Z][\\w:-]*\\s*>' // self-closing tag
    + '|^<[a-zA-Z][\\w-]*(?:attribute)*?\\s*/?>' // open tag
    + '|^<\\?[\\s\\S]*?\\?>' // processing instruction, e.g. <?php ?>
    + '|^<![a-zA-Z]+\\s[\\s\\S]*?>' // declaration, e.g. <!DOCTYPE html>
    + '|^<!\\[CDATA\\[[\\s\\S]*?\\]\\]>',
    // CDATA section
    link: /^!?\[(label)\]\(\s*(href)(?:\s+(title))?\s*\)/,
    reflink: /^!?\[(label)\]\[(?!\s*\])((?:\\[\[\]]?|[^\[\]\\])+)\]/,
    nolink: /^!?\[(?!\s*\])((?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|\\[\[\]]|[^\[\]])*)\](?:\[\])?/,
    reflinkSearch: 'reflink|nolink(?!\\()',
    strong: {
      start: /^(?:(\*\*(?=[*punctuation]))|\*\*)(?![\s])|__/,
      // (1) returns if starts w/ punctuation
      middle: /^\*\*(?:(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^*]|\\\*)|overlapSkip)|\*(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^*]|\\\*)|overlapSkip)*?\*)+?\*\*$|^__(?![\s])((?:(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^_]|\\_)|overlapSkip)|_(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^_]|\\_)|overlapSkip)*?_)+?)__$/,
      endAst: /[^punctuation\s]\*\*(?!\*)|[punctuation]\*\*(?!\*)(?:(?=[punctuation\s]|$))/,
      // last char can't be punct, or final * must also be followed by punct (or endline)
      endUnd: /[^\s]__(?!_)(?:(?=[punctuation\s])|$)/ // last char can't be a space, and final _ must preceed punct or \s (or endline)

    },
    em: {
      start: /^(?:(\*(?=[punctuation]))|\*)(?![*\s])|_/,
      // (1) returns if starts w/ punctuation
      middle: /^\*(?:(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^*]|\\\*)|overlapSkip)|\*(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^*]|\\\*)|overlapSkip)*?\*)+?\*$|^_(?![_\s])(?:(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^_]|\\_)|overlapSkip)|_(?:(?!overlapSkip)(?:[^_]|\\_)|overlapSkip)*?_)+?_$/,
      endAst: /[^punctuation\s]\*(?!\*)|[punctuation]\*(?!\*)(?:(?=[punctuation\s]|$))/,
      // last char can't be punct, or final * must also be followed by punct (or endline)
      endUnd: /[^\s]_(?!_)(?:(?=[punctuation\s])|$)/ // last char can't be a space, and final _ must preceed punct or \s (or endline)
    },
    code: /^(`+)([^`]|[^`][\s\S]*?[^`])\1(?!`)/,
    br: /^( {2,}|\\)\n(?!\s*$)/,
    del: noopTest$1,
    text: /^(`+|[^`])(?:(?= {2,}\n)|[\s\S]*?(?:(?=[\\<!\[`*]|\b_|$)|[^ ](?= {2,}\n)))/,
    punctuation: /^([\s*punctuation])/
  }; // list of punctuation marks from common mark spec
  // without * and _ to workaround cases with double emphasis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/4501

```
// node_modules/hexo_prism_plugin/src/index.js
// L8-L14
const map = {
  '&#39;': '\'',
  '&amp;': '&',
  '&gt;': '>',
  '&lt;': '<',
  '&quot;': '"'
};
```

A workaround is,

```
const map = {
  '&#39;': '\'',
  '&amp;': '&',
  '&gt;': '>',
  '&lt;': '<',
  '&quot;': '"',
  '&#123;': '{',
  '&#125;': '}'
};
```